# 2-Norm of a summation of a 2D vector

Tags: summation, normed-spaces

I have a formula which I need to simplify to write it in a quadratic matrix form of sigma vector $v^T * Q * v $.
$$ \Biggl|\Biggl|\sum_{m=3}^{s-1} \sigma_{i,m} \frac{m!}{(m-2)!} t^{m-2} \Biggr|\Biggr|_{2}^{2}$$

Each $ \sigma_{i,m} $ is a 2x1 vector, for example $[y;z]$. v is a flattened vector of the form $ v = [\sigma_{0,0,y}, \sigma_{0,0,z}, \sigma_{0,1,y}, \sigma_{0,1,z} ... ] $ .  i is an independent iterative variable. Since m is a factor of the summation and $ \sigma_{i,m} $ is a vector, I was not sure how to do the norm.
Is the formula below equivalent?
$$ \sum_{n=4}^{s-1} \sum_{m=4}^{s-1} \sigma_{i,m} . \sigma_{i,n} \frac{n! m!}{(n-2)! (m-2)!} t^{n+m-4} $$

where $\sigma_{i,m} . \sigma_{i,n}$ is the dot product, i.e. $\sigma_{i,m,y}*\sigma_{i,n,y} + \sigma_{i,m,z}*\sigma_{i,n,z}$